# This is possible that in label that given navigation Click?

Tags: blackberry

i am one Blackberry developer and i built one application that to view multiple location and point thus user go the point at that time they show is address and they click label then push screen to another page.This type application done then how to do?

public class GpsScreen extends FullScreen{
 LabelField label;
 public GpsScreen() {
  super(DEFAULT_CLOSE);
  label=new LabelField(){

protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
    Dialog.alert("Hi");
    return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);
   }
  };

String document = "" 
   + "" 
   + "" 
   + "" 
   + "" 
   + "" 
   + ""
   + ""
    + "";
  Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,document));

}

Here i given code thus given me solution with some example .some urgent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
LabelField label=new LabelField("click"){

        protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) { 
            Dialog.alert("track wheel click"); 
            return true; 
            }
        protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
            if(character == '\n'){
                Dialog.alert("enter button press"); 
                return true;
            }
            return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello dear here i give label in string so i not pass this type.Bec. here i given one String document.

String document="<lbs>"+ "<location lat='4542349' lon='-7569792' label='Ottawa, ON, CANADA'/>"+"</lbs>";
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,document));

so i this type add .
if any other solution then forward me.